# How to efficiently unpack data from socket.recv()?

Tags: python, performance, sockets, buffer, slice

I'm looking to optimize by socket receive calls in Python by specifying the receive size after ever call to it.  I receive a 6 byte header (First 4 are blank, last 2 are big-endian).  The idea is that I get the size of the message I want by unpacking the first 6 bytes, then with that resulting integer value, set my receive buffer to that specific value, read the socket and add the result immediately to my list.  Here's my code snippet:

```
engine_messages = []
try:
    while True:
        size_header = struct.unpack('!4cH', self.iosocket.recv(6))[4]
        socket_payload = self.iosocket.recv(size_header)
        engine_messages.append(socket_payload)
except struct.error:
    print 'we received 0 bytes; end of stream'
finally:
    self.iosocket.close()
```

The problem is that when I do my test runs, it returns RANDOM results.  Sometimes, I get a list of 10 items back, sometimes 100 and sometimes the expected value.  When I set the receive buffer to `4096`, I always received correct amount of replies.  But in doing so, I have to `"".join()` my list and perform expensive string slicing to get my rows.  Now, this isn't a big deal with resultsets of hundreds/thousands.  The problem is that processing time starts to climb when I work through a "joined" list of hundreds of thousands or million of records in where each row is around 2500+ characters.

By populating the list right from the stream, it would bump up the socket calls but not by much and would SUBSTANTIALLY save me time overall.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Running on Python 2.7.8 / Mac and 2.7.8 / Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you ***assume*** the [`socket.recv()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) call always reads the number of bytes given as the argument. In fact, it might read ***less*** then that - whatever is available in the OS network stack buffers at the moment waiting for your app to consume. That effectively breaks alignment of your protocol messages in the stream.

You need to check sizes returned from both socket calls and buffer at the application level accordingly.

Note: you didn't specify, but I'm assuming TCP here from the mentioning of "stream" in the exception handling block.

Comment: Ah, I see that my assumption made me look silly. Nevertheless, you are correct, this is a TCP stream. Now, if I understood you correctly, adding this buffer check would add overhead, would it not? Is there a pattern that would do something similar?  I always strive to be as Pythonic wherever I can.

Comment: Thinking about your answer further, I am now understanding what's going on under the hood.   My logic is very cursory at best and would need to implement further inspection of the buffer and receive accordingly.  From what I've gathered, my socket logic is to greedy and just needs to be scrutinized more.  Really enjoyed your answer and had me thinking it more thoroughly.

Comment: I would not consider making appropriate checks to be "overhead". You want your program to be correct first, and fast second. No real use for broken zooming-quick code :)

Comment: No, of course.. you're absolutely correct.  I was a bit naive on my thoughts on socket data receive.  I will do some quick benchmarks and provide some color, thereafter.

Comment: After some re-working of my code, I was able to implement logic to properly check payload sizes.  I think taking your comment and really thinking things through really helped me understand and optimize my code.